# Error C2011: 'XX' : 'class' type redefinition

Tags: c++, class

I have this compiler error (C2011) with this piece of code. I don't know what is wrong with it.

The namespace (Ogre) doesn't have a definition for `PlaneMovement`. I also tried a different name and still the same errors.

```
#include <Ogre.h>

using namespace Ogre;

class PlaneMovement
{
public:
    PlaneMovement(Degree startingAngle, Real velocity = 2, Real gravity = 2);
    Vector2 updateMovement(const FrameEvent& evt);
private:
    Degree currentAngle;
    Real currentVelocityX;
    Real currentVelocityY;
    Real gravity;
    bool top;
};
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Include guards:

```
#ifndef FILE_H
#define FILE_H

//file contents here

#endif
```

Header files should have include guards for this exact reason - multiple inclusion in the same translation unit can lead to a multiple definition.

The alternative is using

```
#pragma once
```

but this isn't supported by all compilers.

Comment: I don't get it. I should define those again in my .cpp file?

Comment: @Pacha no, you should surround your header files with them (replace `FILE_H` with the name of your file).

Comment: Another thing, should I include them on the .cpp files too? Instead of ``CLASSNAME_H``, ``CLASSNAME_CPP``?

Comment: @Pacha no, cpp files don't require them.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else faces this situation, it may be when library includes in property of project and header files from this library include in projects file.

Answer (score 0):

### Incorrect Forward Declaration

Another possible cause, if you're a goof like me, could be that you used `enum` instead of `class` when forward declaring a `class`.

File1.h

```
namespace MyNamespace { enum NotActuallyAnEnum; }
```

File2.h

```
class NotActuallyAnEnum

{
...
}
```

This will produce something like the following error:

```
error C2011: 'enum' type redefinition
```

Obviously the fix is to correct the forward declaration:

```
namespace MyNamespace { class NotActuallyAnEnum; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also get this error if you have multiple branches of your project on your development station and use a symlink to point to one of them.

Let's suppose you have two different branches of your solution called `Project1` and `Project2` and you let a symlink called `Project` point to either `Project1` or `Project2`.

The idea is that you could switch between branches and the project would always appear to be `Project` to your application and possibly some other tools that expect it there.

**Disclaimer**: yes, version control can switch between branches, but this way you will not have to rebuild the whole application every single time you switch branches. Besides both branches can still be under version control.

Okay, so opening `Project` would open either `Project1` or `Project2` depending on the symlink. The symlink could be removed/created by some simple `mklink_1` and `mklink_2` like script files.

Here comes the pitfall:

If you don't pay attention and directly open the solution at location 1 or 2 directly (instead of following the directory symlink with Visual Studio), the pre-processor might be tricked into mixing `Project1\MyHeader.h` (or `MyProject2\MyHeader.h`) with `MyProject\MyHeader.h`!

Even those are technically the same file, the preprocessor doesn't know about the symlink. So here the `#pragma once` would not save you!